# Google Play Billing Library v4 проверка покупок в приложении

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-billing

Я использую Google Play Billing Library v4 для покупок в приложений Android
(`implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0"`)

Я не нашел никаких методов, которые могут проверить покупку продукта пользователем.
**Если пользователь переустановил приложение, как мне проверить и восстановить все покупки в приложении?**

Все найденные мной варианты предлагают мне использовать метод API Developer Google Play: `Purchases.products.get`
**Всегда ли для этого требуется сервер?**
Во всяком случае, мне это кажется слишком сложным для простой задачи.

Я использовал это решение ([anjlab / android-inapp-billing-v3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)), но эта библиотека больше не поддерживается, и я решил разобраться, как работает биллинг от Google в последней версии.

Я не хотел бы использовать устаревший метод. `queryPurchases`.
Думаю, и этот метод мне не поможет `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync`, потому что `onPurchaseHistoryResponse` возвращает [*"productId", purchaseToken", "purchaseTime", "quantity", "developerPayload"*] причем последние два параметра могут отсутствовать или иметь значение *null* (Это я проверил в своем приложений)

Вопрос:
Как мне просто реализовать проверку всех моих товаров (3ш) на наличие оплаты пользователем в приложении. Если пользователь переустановил приложение или сменил телефон. Мне нужно восстановить покупки пользователю.

Comment: В документации рекомендуют использовать BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(), вот и восстанавливайте.

Comment: Я так понимаю этот метод возвращает ответ только если совершена покупка и ее нужно обработать (предоставить пользователю, подтвердить и потратить если нужно). Сколько я тестировал там всегда пусто. Ответ всегда получаю в PurchasesUpdatedListener. Как я понял этот метод нужен для получения ответа о покупке совершенных где то еще или еще что то...

Comment: Метод возвращает все покупки, в том числе подтвержденные isAcknowledged()

Comment: Странно у меня всегда возвращает пустоту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При инициализации клиента передается слушатель `purchasesUpdatedListener`

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();
```

Ну и сам слушатель

```
private final PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                && purchases != null) {
            //обработка покупки
        } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
            //если покупка уже была сделана ранее
            //получаем список ранее сделанных покупок
            billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP,
                    listenerPurchasesResponsAlreadyOwned);
        } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            //здесь можно написать, что мне очень жаль, что покупка была отменена
        } else {
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Что бы я получил в этом слушателе ответ с кодом ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED, пользователь (или автоматом) должен запустить процесс покупки. То есть нажать кнопку купить и получить ошибку, что товар куплен.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я немного разобрался с постоянными покупками. То есть в queryPurchaseHistoryAsync, я так понимаю onPurchaseHistoryResponse вернет все покупки когда либо сделанные пользователем. И если покупка потрачена, она все равно будет присутствовать в ответе. Собственно это меня и смущало.

Comment: @Freqnsy, употребление покупки (consume) вполне возможно, но не обязательно. Я, например, этого реализовывать не стал, но вполне можно ведь покупать один и тот же товар несколько раз. К сожалению, как это правильно учесть я не знаю, небыло такой задачи.

Comment: @Freqnsy, что касается "То есть нажать кнопку купить и получить ошибку", то этого делать не обязательно. Я запускаю процесс инициализации биллинга и все делается в фоне, в том числе и проверка ранее сделанных покупок. Если они совершены, выполняю нужные действия, например отключаю рекламу.

Comment: @dubok79, подскажите, будет ли эта проверка на ранее купленный работать спустя год, к примеру? То есть я могу сделать оплату отмены рекламы без своего сервера?